# random realizations given probability

Tags: python, math

I have a features matrix X (Nx3) and a labeled target y (Nx1).
The number of labels is 7.
I want to predict to X_new (Mx3)

I use random forest

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
clf.fit(X,y)
prediction=clf.predict(X_new)
probability=clf.predit_proba(X_new)
```

Now, I have prediction (Mx1) and probability (Mx7).

I want to make 1000 random realizations from the prediction, using of course the probability. That means, if probability==1 in one predicted value, it will never change, while if probability==0.5 it can vary.
Where can I start looking?

Comment: Assuming the labels are number 0,1,2,3,4,5,6, then: `import random; realisations = [random.choices(range(7), weights=w) for w in probability]` or `import numpy.random; realisations = [numpy.random.choice(7, p=w) for w in probability]`